# Hide additional info window on google map

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

I have highlighted country India and Mexico using fusion table query and I have added some marker for country India when I click on marker it's popup properly with his hyperlink.

My problem is that when I click on map except the my custom marker it's popup one info window like bellow snap.It contains some information about the place.

Demo:-[Click Here](http://test.skovian.com/map-heighlight/examples/index.html)

[image: map]

Here I want hide that additional info window except marker info window which open on when you click on marker.

Sample Code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    var layer; // Fusion Tables layer

var tableid = 420419;


var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                        '/static/img/icon-pin.png',
                        new google.maps.Size(68, 80),
                        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                        new google.maps.Point(19, 49));

        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.91129,-10.14098),
          zoom:3,
           el: '#map',
          disableDefaultUI: false,
          draggable: true, 
          zoomControl: true, 
          scrollwheel: true,
          icon: image,


        };

          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);



        new_boundary = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();



        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.2743980, 133.7751360),
            icon:new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            "/profiles/image/9",
            new google.maps.Size(68, 49),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(19, 49)),
            flat: true,
            anchor: 8,

          });

            new_boundary.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(-25.2743980, 133.7751360));



        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-40.9005570, 174.8859710),
            icon:new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            "/profiles/image/2",
            new google.maps.Size(68, 49),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(19, 49)),
            flat: true,
            anchor: 8,

          });
new_boundary.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(-40.9005570, 174.8859710));



            //map.fitBounds(new_boundary);


layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {select: "kml_4326", 
          from: tableid,
         // where: "name_0 = 'India'"},
           where: "name_0 IN ('Mexico','India')"},

  styles: [{
  polygonOptions: {
    strokeWeight: "0",
    //strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    //strokeOpacity: "0.4",
    fillOpacity: "0.1",
    fillColor: "#FF0000"

  }
}]}); 
layer.setMap(map);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppress the infowindow on your FusionTablesLayer (set the [suppressInfoWindows option](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayerOptions) to true):

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  suppressInfoWindows: true,  // ** set suppressInfowindows: true
  query: {select: "kml_4326", 
          from: tableid,
           where: "name_0 IN ('Mexico','India')"},
  styles: [{
  polygonOptions: {
    strokeWeight: "0",
    fillOpacity: "0.1",
    fillColor: "#FF0000"

  }
}]}); 
layer.setMap(map);
```